# Audio only calls with google hangouts

Tags: google-hangouts

Is there a way to make audio only calls with Hangouts? My data plan is very limited (100 MB), and I do not want to waste it on video.

Comment: Not really, no. But a Hangout can be used to call a telephone number.

Comment: AFAIK you can initiate a call, and then turn off the camera − which basically would make it an "audio only call".

Comment: Would turning off the camera reduce significantly the data usage?

Comment: @András I would assume so. Video is larger compared to audio.

Comment: I knew that part I am just not sure hangouts will not keep sending the blank screen as video. It will not be a lot because of the compression, but still.